# I want to make a div responsive to window and height of the second div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div's frist changeable without scroll (the red one) and the second div (black) height should change to fill max size of screen (the second one have scroll). Any ideas how to do this? I dont want to give the red one a scroll.

Adding code what have i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var h = $("#topContainer").height();
            var heightBottomContent = $(window).height() - h;
            $("#botContainer").height(heightBottomContent);
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: `"I want to make a div responsive to window and height of the second div"` and I want to go to space ... Both seem possible but the real question is what have we tried so far ...

Comment: the problem is that I dont know how to do it so i attached picture, and I asked a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have solved your own problem, just have to implement it on window `load` & `resize` event:

```
$(window).on('load',fix_height).on('resize',fix_height);

function fix_height() {
    var h = $("#topContainer").height();
    var heightBottomContent = $(window).height() - h;
    $("#botContainer").height(heightBottomContent);
}
```